# What does <> mean when defining an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, class, interface

I learning about writing my own interfaces and came across the MSDN article "[Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)". Everything seems fine, except: what does <T> mean or do?

```
interface IEquatable<T>
{
    bool Equals(T obj);
}
```

Comment: T is for Type, meaning it is a Generic interface which can support multiple types.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It means that it is a [*generic*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx) interface.

You could create an interface like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T TheThing {get; set;}
}
```

and you could implement it in various ways:

```
public class MyStringClass : IMyInterface<string>
{
    public string TheThing {get; set;}
}
```

and like this:

```
public class MyIntClass : IMyInterface<int>
{
    public int TheThing {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is there any reason that T is used?

Comment: @eddy556: It's just a convention - T is used to represent "any type T" - however, sometimes you'll see other things (ie: Dictionary<TKey,TValue>, etc)

Comment: `T` is just a naming convention, because the generic argument name references a _T_ype. You could name it more or less whatever you want, but as it is a convention to name interfaces starting with an I it also a convention to name the generic type parameter(s) starting with T. In the above example it could just aswell have been named `TTheThing` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

It is a parametric type means that you could reuse IEquatable for any type... at "runtime" (but not exactly), in place of T, you could use String, Animal, Dog ecc...